# When using JUnit's @Parameterized, can I have some tests still run only once

Tags: java, junit, junit4, parameterized

I use `@Parameterized` in many cases to run tests on a number of permutations. This works very well and keeps the test-code itself simple and clean.

However sometimes I would like to have some of the test-methods still run only once as they do not make use of the parameters, is there a way with JUnit to mark the test-method as "singleton" or "run-once"?

Note: This does not concern running single tests in Eclipse, I know how to do that :)

Comment: It sounds like those tests shouldn't be in the same suite as the parameterized tests, then.

Comment: yep, that's the only solution that came to my mind, but I really like to have "related" tests in one suite, e.g. all tests for one class in one test-class...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can associate any number of test classes to run together using a suite. This way all the tests are run when you test your class and you can mix different test runners.

1. Create a test suite associated with the class you are testing
2. Add a reference to the parameterized test class
3. Add the other class(es) containing non parameterized tests.

   ```
   import org.junit.runners.Suite;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

   @RunWith(Suite.class)
   @Suite.SuiteClasses({ParameterizedTestClass.class, UnitTests.class, MoreUnitTests.class})
   public class SutTestSuite{
        //Empty...
   }
   ```

Comment: Yeah, that's propably what I will end up with, I hoped there would be something like an annotation for single test-methods...

Answer (score 119):

You could structure your test with the [Enclosed runner](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/experimental/runners/Enclosed.html).

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class TestClass {

    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public static class TheParameterizedPart {

        @Parameters
        public static Object[][] data() {
            ...
        }

        @Test
        public void someTest() {
            ...
        }

        @Test
        public void anotherTest() {
            ...
        }
    }

    public static class NotParameterizedPart {
        @Test
        public void someTest() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about Enclosed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there is a number of junit plugins that give you some more features/power regarding parameterized tests. check zohhak, junit-parames and junit-dataprovider. they allow you to mix parametrized and simple junit tests

Answer (score 1):

Before I knew about "@RunWith(Enclosed.class)" approach, I used the following (similar) solution, with inner classes extending outer class. I keep using this structure because I like that the tests are in same place and share some properties and methods and things seems clearer to me. Then, using Eclipse, in my run configuration, I choose that option "Run all tests in the selected project, package or source folder" and all these tests will be performed with just a click.

```
public class TestBooksDAO {

    private static BooksDAO dao;

    @Parameter(0)
    public String title;
    @Parameter(1)
    public String author;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        dao = BooksDAO.getInstancia();
    }

    /** Tests that run only once. */
    public static class SingleTests extends TestBooksDAO {

        @Test(timeout=10000)
        public void testGetAll() {
            List<Book> books = dao.getBooks();
            assertNotNull(books);
            assertTrue(books.size()>0);
        }

        @Test(timeout=10000)
        public void testGetNone() {
            List<Book> books = dao.getBooks(null);
            assertNull(books);
        }
    }

    /** Tests that run for each set of parameters. */
    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public static class ParameterizedTests1 extends TestBooksDAO {

        @Parameters(name = "{index}: author=\"{2}\"; title=\"{0}\";")
        public static Collection<Object[]> values() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { 
                {"title1", ""}, 
                {"title2", ""}, 
                {"title3", ""}, 
                {"title4", "author1"}, 
                {"title5", "author2"}, 
            });
        }

        @Test(timeout=10000)
        public void testGetOneBook() {
            Book book = dao.getBook(author, title);
            assertNotNull(book);
        }
    }

    /** Other parameters for different tests. */
    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public static class ParameterizedTests2 extends TestBooksDAO {

        @Parameters(name = "{index}: author=\"{2}\";")
        public static Collection<Object[]> values() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { 
                {"", "author1"}, 
                {"", "author2"}, 
                {"", "author3"}, 
            });
        }

        @Test(timeout=10000)
        public void testGetBookList() {
            List<Book> books = dao.getBookByAuthor(author);
            assertNotNull(books);
            assertTrue(books.size()>0);
        }
    }
}
```