# Run specific JUnit tests multiple times, but exclude others from running multiple times

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I am using `Parameterized` JUnit runner to run some of my tests multiple times. Here is the template of my test class

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class TestClass {

    private String key;
    private boolean value;

    public TestClass(String key, boolean value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
            {"key1", true},
            {"key2", true},
            {"key3", false}
        };
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void testKeys() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testValues() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testNotRelatedKeyValue() {
    }
}
```

Now, I want my test methods - `testKeys(), testValues()` to run with different parameter values which they are running.

However, I my last method - `testNotRelatedKeyValue()` is also executing that many times along with other parameterized tests.

I don't want `testNotRelatedKeyValue()` to run multiple times, but just once.

Is it possible in this class or would I need to create a new test class?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776335/when-using-junits-parameterized-can-i-have-some-tests-still-run-only-once

Comment: So basically, I will have to split my test class into separate test classes and ````Suite```` feature to run them. There isn't any direct way of doing it.

Comment: If you want the test to be the part of same class then this is the recommended way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could structure your test with the [Enclosed runner](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/experimental/runners/Enclosed.html).

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class TestClass {

    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public static class TheParameterizedPart {
        @Parameter(0)
        public String key;

        @Parameter(1)
        private boolean value;

        @Parameters
        public static Object[][] data() {
            return new Object[][] {
                {"key1", true},
                {"key2", true},
                {"key3", false}
            };
        }

        @Test
        public void testKeys() {
            ...
        }

        @Test
        public void testValues() {
            ...
        }
    }

    public static class NotParameterizedPart {
        @Test
        public void testNotRelatedKeyValue() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```