# Parameterize some tests but not others with RobolectricTest

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I am looking to add a parameterized test to an existing test suite that uses the Robolectric test framework, like so:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SomeTest {
    /* ... Tons of tests */
}
```

One of the tests is for functionality that used to be fixed but now takes a parameter. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35057629/467366) suggests that in order to run just the one test in a parameterized fashion, I should add `@RunWith(Enclosed.class)`, then wrap the test I want to parameterize in its own class. Unfortunately, it seems that I must choose *either* `Enclosed.class` *or* `RobolectricTestRunner.class`, not both.

There seems to be an [open issue on `robolectric`](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2946) related to this, but the answer in the issue seems to be to wrap the whole test in `@RunWith(Enclosed.class)`, then wrap the inner tests in a class with `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`. Given that I'm only changing one test in a fairly large set of test cases, I'm not amazingly comfortable with the idea of refactoring everything to be in a set of inner classes.

Is there any way to get the Robolectric test runner to parameterize one test from a larger suite?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to do that by using *Enclosed* the following way (code is in kotlin):

```kotlin
@RunWith(Enclosed::class)
internal class WhateverTest {

    @RunWith(ParameterizedRobolectricTestRunner::class)
    internal class WhateverTestParametrized(private val parameter: ParameterType) {
        // parametrized tests
    }

    @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
    internal class WhateverTestNotParametrized {
        // Not parametrized tests
    }
}
```

I know you wanted not to have inner classes for the tests but it's the only way I've found to get the Robolectric test runner to parameterize one test from a larger suite as asked for in junit 4.