# Parameterized Instrumented Tests for Android

Tags: android, testing, junit4, android-instrumentation, testing-support-library

The answer to [AndroidJUnit4 and Parameterized tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538008/androidjunit4-and-parameterized-tests) links to a Google example for using `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)`. However, this is a simple unit test. How do I run parameterized **instrumented** tests?

Answer (score -2):

Actually, you should put your test with `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` runner in the `androidTest` folder instead of `test` folder. That test will be run on the emulator and you will be able to unit test classes with android dependencies, like `android.graphics.Rect` etc. 
Of course, don't forget

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
```

and dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
}
```

Comment: So I just use a ActivityRule and still get full instrumentation? Even without AndroidJUnit4?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. Yes. By the way, you don't need runner annotation at all if you have set testInstrumentationRunner in gradle. You can just try to make sure

Comment: Even though this question old, it is still relevant to an ongoing project of mine. I will give this a try when I can and give you an accept and up vote after I confirm. Don't hold your breathe, though. Also thanks for the extra info regarding test runners.